# VirtualBox - Sharing a folder

Tags: folders, error, sharing, virtualbox

I'm a Windows 10 user, running macOS High Sierra 10.13 via VirtualBox 5.1.28.
I didn't fully understand how to share a folder.
The part that I did understand and did, is:

1. Devices → Insert Guest Additions CD image...
2. [image]

But then, in macOS, I type in the terminal:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf release_builds ~/Downloads/SteamCMD-GUI
```

And I get the error:

```
mount: exec /Library/Filesystems/vboxsf.fs/Contents/Resources/mount_vboxsf for /Users/avi12/Downloads/SteamCMD-GUI: No such file or directory
```

Later, I checked the directory `/Library/Filesystems`, and found that:
[image]
Which means that, there's actually no directory `vboxsf.fs`, so there would obviously be an error.

The question is then, what part am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

There are no guest additions for macOS in VirtualBox. The shared folder feature of VirtualBox won't work here.

You have to configure a share on the host system and access it from inside the guest with one of the common methods:

1. Finder > Go > Connect to server... <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>
2. Terminal: `mount -t smbfs //username:password@server/share .../mountpoint`
3. Finder window > sidebar > Shared > choose share >

Some network connection between host and guest is required (e.g NAT or bridged adapter). Using the latter requires to set up an IP-address in macOS in the same network as the host's adapter.

---

To set up a bridged adapter for a guest (which has to be shut down) do the following:

1. Choose the VM > Settings > Network > Adapter 1 > Check *Enable Network Adapter* > Attached to > Bridged Adapter > choose a network interface of the host (usually either Ethernet or Wi-Fi)
2. Check the IP config of this interface in the host (e.g. IP= 192.168.0.2 Netmask= 255.255.255.0 Gateway=192.168.0.1 DNS=8.8.8.8)
3. Use the same config in the guest but choose a different IP (e.g. 192.168.0.111)
4. Connect from the guest to the host with <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> > enter smb://192.168.0.2/Share_name > enter the credentials

Comment: In step 2, I typed: `mount -t smbfs //avi12:1@server/share ~/Downloads/SteamCMD-GUI`. The error output: `mount_smbfs: server connection failed: No route to host`

Comment: So how do I solve the problem?

Comment: I see now that the network is NAT. Is the IP set by the IPv4 or public IP?

Comment: I thought at first that you meant the network configuration in the macOS settings in VirtualBox. In VirtualBox's Preferences → NAT Networks, the list is empty at this moment.

Comment: @avi12 Both are important!

Comment: Oh, alright, but what do I configure in VirtualBox's Preferences?

Comment: The current configuration is: [https://i.imgur.com/AUQy4k6.png](https://i.imgur.com/AUQy4k6.png)